# How to get contents from 2 files and append that contents to a new file using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, paste

I have 2 files which look like this

file1.txt

```
GYFUFGYO1  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
GYFUFGYO2  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
GYFUFGYG3  AFP-Login   nathan@qt.com  BUG
GYFUFGYG4  AFP-Login   nathan@qt.com  BUG
GYFUFGYO5  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
GYFUFGYO6  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
```

file2.txt

```
MAC 135 2022-09-02-09:35
```

I have to append those contents(file1, file2) to file3.txt
then **expected output** is

```
GYFUFGYO1  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL MAC 135 2022-09-02-09:35
GYFUFGYO2  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL MAC 135 2022-09-02-09:35
GYFUFGYG3  AFP-Login   nathan@qt.com  BUG     MAC 135 2022-09-02-09:35
GYFUFGYG4  AFP-Login   nathan@qt.com  BUG     MAC 135 2022-09-02-09:35
GYFUFGYO5  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL MAC 135 2022-09-02-09:35
GYFUFGYO6  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL MAC 135 2022-09-02-09:35
```

this is what I tried

```
paste -s file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

then output is (file3.txt)

```
GYFUFGYO1  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL   GYFUFGYO2  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL   GYFUFGYG3  AFP-Login   nathan@qt.com  BUG       GYFUFGYG4  AFP-Login   nathan@qt.com  BUG       GYFUFGYO5  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL   GYFUFGYO6  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
BAU 133 2022-09-02-09:35
```

Can someone help me to figure out this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try like: `awk 'NR==1{val=$0;nextfile} {print $0,val}' file2  file1` considering your file2 has only 1 line. Should work in GNU `awk`.

Comment: thanks for your support. but after executing this command, I am not getting the expected output: this is the output I am getting now    >                                               
BAU 133 2022-09-02-09:35 GYFUFGYO1  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL

Comment: Where is the string `BAU 133` from? It looks neither of file1.txt and file2.txt contain such a string. Please make sure your input files have proper Unix line endings. If they have DOS line endings. fix them with [dos2unix](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` expects two file of equal length. I'm guessing you basically want this common Awk two-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } NR==FNR { a[++i] = $0; next }
    { print $0, a[(FNR-1) % i + 1] }' file2.txt file1.txt
```

(I have assumed your files are tab-separated; it's not clear from your question.)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `file2.txt` has just one line as shown, how about a `paste` solution:

```
paste file1.txt <(yes $(<file2.txt) | head -n $(wc -l <file1.txt))
```

- `yes $(<file2.txt)` repeats the line of file2.txt.
- `$(wc -l <file1.txt)` returns the line count of file1.txt.
- `head -n $(wc -l <file1.txt)` prints as many lines as file1.txt.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `file2.txt` has always exactly 1 line, then you might exploit GNU `sed`'s hold space, consider following simple example let `file1.txt` content be

```
123
456
789
```

and `file2.txt` file content be

```
ABC
```

then

```
sed -e '1{h;d}' -e 'G;s/\n/ /' file2.txt file1.txt
```

gives output

```
123 ABC
456 ABC
789 ABC
```

Explanation: I register two actions, for 1 line (*globally*, that is first line of first of mentioned file, observe that it is `file2.txt file1.txt` not in reverse) I instruct GNU `sed` to save line into hold space (`h`) and immediately go further without output anything (`d`), for other lines I instruct GNU `sed` to append newline and content of hold space (`G`) and then replace said newline with space characters.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.5)*

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{v=$0; next} {print $0, v}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Set `OFS` to `\t` or pipe the output to `column -t` to get whatever separators/alignment you like if a blank isn't adequate.

Answer (score 0):

assuming `file2` ***only*** has 1 line

```
cat temptest_f_00_01.txt 
123
456
789

cat temptest_f_00_02.txt
ABC
```

> ```
> mawk -F'^$' 'FNR<NR || _*(ORS=" "$_ RS)' f2.txt f1.txt
> ```

```
123 ABC
456 ABC
789 ABC
```